# MonacaIDEへのカスタムプラグインのインポートについて

Tags: html5, cordova, monaca

MonacaIDEに自作したCordovaプラグインをインポートすることはできますか。

Comment: もし、試行記録、エラーログなどがあれば質問で共有をしてください。　http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/file/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gold プラン以上が必要になりますが、自作の Cordova プラグインをインポートして利用することが可能です。

参考: [Asial BLOG: Cordova/PhoneGapプラグインを使おう](http://blog.asial.co.jp/1348)